# How to add items to a map in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` with nodejs (lambda functions on AWS)

I've to a db called `Translations`, primary key `Term`, sort key `Category`.

Basically I'm trying to write data in like this:

```
{ 
  Term: 'hello_there', 
  Category: 'common_phrases', 
  Translations: {
    en-ca: 'Hello There!'
  } 
}
```

and I want to update Translations Map to perhaps add another language, or just modify the `en-ca` portion of the object.

I've tried the following:

```
let params = {
    TableName: 'Translations',
    Key: {
      Term: 'hello_there',
      Category: 'common_phrases',
    },
    UpdateExpression:
      'SET Translations.#lang = list_append(Translations, :term)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':term': 'french version',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#lang': 'fr-ca',
    },
  }
```

But I get an error about the wrong operand type.

I've tried:

```
    UpdateExpression:
      'SET Translations.#lang = :term',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':term': 'french version',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#lang': 'fr-ca',
    },
```

But this overwrites the entire contents of the Translations field. Meaning that if I already had `en-ca` in there, now I would only have `fr-ca`.

I tried this as well, but also get an operand error:

```
{
  UpdateExpression: 'ADD Translations :term',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':term': { 'fr-ff': 'frenchterm' },
},
```

Any suggestions on how to add/update items to the Translations Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SET` expression was close, try something like this:

```
    UpdateExpression:
      'SET #trans.#lang = :term',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':term': 'french version',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#trans': 'Translations`,
      '#lang': 'fr-ca',
    },
```

Comment: Thank you! To clarify this for myself next time I search for it, the trick is to put all parts of object path into  `ExpressionAttributeNames`